# SoftLayer API Nessus Scan Status / Report via PHP

Tags: php, api, security, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, nessus

To generate/initiate a new vulnerability scan at SoftLayer, this works (for every server in an account):

```
    require_once('SoapClient.class.php');
    $apiUsername = "omitted";
    $apiKey = "omitted";

    $client = SoftLayer_SoapClient::getClient('SoftLayer_Account', null, $apiUsername, $apiKey);

    $accountInfo = $client->getObject();
    $hardware = $client->getHardware();

    foreach ($hardware as $server){
        $scanclient = SoftLayer_SoapClient::getClient('SoftLayer_Network_Security_Scanner_Request', '', $apiUsername, $apiKey);

        $scantemplate = new stdClass();
        $scantemplate->accountId = $accountInfo->id;
        $scantemplate->hardwareId = $server->id;
        $scantemplate->ipAddress = $server->primaryIpAddress;
        try{
                // Successfully creates new scan
                $scan = $scanclient->createObject($scantemplate);
        } catch (Exception $e){
                echo $e->getMessage() . "\n\r";
        }
    }
```

When changing

```
$reportstatus = $scanclient->createObject($scantemplate);
```

to

```
$reportstatus = $scanclient->getReport($scantemplate);
```

The API responds with an error concerning "Object does not exist to execute method on.".

Would SoftLayer_Network_Security_Scanner_RequestInitParameters be required as per the docs? If so how do you define these "init parameters" and attach to the request for status or report?

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Security_Scanner_Request/getReport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the init parameter using the Softlayer PHP client you can do that like this:

When you are creating the client:

```
$virtualGuestService = SoftLayer_SoapClient::getClient('SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest', $initParemter, $username, $key);
```

Or after creating the client:

```
$virtualGuestService = SoftLayer_SoapClient::getClient('SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest', null, $username, $key);
# Setting the init parameter
$virtualGuestService->setInitParameter($virtualGuestId);
```

The init parameter is basically the id of the object you wish to get edit or delete, in this case the init parameter is the id of the vulnerability scan you wish to get the report.

You can try this code:

```
$scanclient = SoftLayer_SoapClient::getClient('SoftLayer_Network_Security_Scanner_Request', '', $apiUsername, $apiKey);
$scanclient->setInitParameter(15326); # The id of the vulnerability scan
$reportstatus = $scanclient->getReport();
```

To get the list of your vulnerabilities scans in a VSI you can use this method:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getSecurityScanRequests
and for bare metal servers you can use this one:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/getSecurityScanRequests

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and example, worked like a charm.